# What is this C++ warning - control reaches end of non-void function

Tags: c++

I am writing this function definition.

```
#include<iostream>

int abs_fun(int x);

int main()
{
    int i =abs_fun(0);
    std::cout<<i;
    return 0;
}

int abs_fun(int x)
{
    if (x<0)
        return -x;
    else if(x>=0) //warning
        return x;
}
```

I am compiling the code using `g++ -Wall -Wconversion -Wextra p4.cpp -o p4` and getting warning at the end of `abs_fun()` as `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] }` If I just write `else` instead of `else if`, then warning goes away. Any suggestions why does warning appear?

Comment: Are you asking why the compiler does not "analyze" the conditions or are you really just asking what "control reaches end of non-void function" means?

Comment: In an `if` - `else if` structure, there is potential that both conditions test false, in which case control would reach the end of the function. Your compiler is not smart enough to detect that - for the conditions you have specified - the end of the function is not reached.  That would be because it is easier to write code in the compiler that detects the presence of `if`, followed by `else if`, and recognises there is no final `else` than it would be to write code to examine ALL the conditions.

Answer (score 5):

Because the compiler is not smart enough (or just doesn't bother trying) to understand that one of the `return`s is always reached.

Comment: Note that most popular compilers are probably smart enough to detect this and are likely to do so during optimization passes. However, the standard doesn't require them to take that information into account when producing this diagnostic so most won't.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of an `if` and `else`, if both the `if` and `else` branch return you can be sure that something returns in all cases.

In your case, it requires an analyses to determine that the conditions fully cover all possible use cases which the compiler is not required to do. In this case it's pretty straight forward, but consider more complicated conditions. If such simple conditions were required to be analyzed, it would be a case of "where do we draw the line?" in terms of what complexity should the compiler be expected to analyze.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all control paths should either throw exception or return some value. Doing otherwise is undefined behavior, so compiler wants to warn you about that. In your case, compiler cannot prove that all execution paths lead to return/exception.

### Why?

Because doing the check is expensive. Sometimes it might not even be possible. As a result, compiler just doesn't have such feature.

### In which cases?

Well, this is more about discrete math.